# JQuery image preload - dynamic set of images

Tags: jquery, preload

I have a slider which keeps animating the background images.The background images are being applied to the body element of the page i.e it takes the full size of the page.

This animation is seen on the home page... there are total 10 images in the slider which are fetched from the database.

My question is how should I preload these images since most of these images are more than 200-300KB in size.The jquery preload needs a static array of image names, but while loading I don't knew their names.

So can you guys help me to preload these dynamic images?

Comment: So, you're asking to preload images that you don't know the filenames for?  Can't be done. You need a URL for an image in order to load or preload it.

Comment: yes while loading I don't knew the image names since these values are being returned from the db.So should I first send an ajax request to get the file names?

Comment: When you have the image filenames, you can start the preload.  So, do whatever you need to do to get the filenames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple script which helps to load images before hand using javascript.

```
    $.each(data, function(index, item) {
        var tempImage = new Image();
        tempImage.src = item.url;
        preloadedImages.push(tempImage);
    }


where data as an array of image data 
data=
{
   name:'NameofImage',
   url:'http://www.website.com/image1.jpg',
}
```

To display the images you can simply add the images to the DOM

```
 $("img").attr({
                src: item.src
            }).appendTo("#target");
```

I have a simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frictionless/bfJFX/)  which demonstartes the script. It takes data from an ajax request and pre-loads the images. When the user does a mouseover the target it attaches the image to the DOM.

*Below is the screenshot showing the images are being loaded at the time the page gets loaded:*

[image: Net tab of firefox showing the images being preloaded]

this [reference link](http://perishablepress.com/press/2007/07/22/css-throwdown-preload-images-without-javascript/) argues that images loaded in div which are hidden might not be pre-loaded in some of the browsers like Opera. I thought haven't verified it.

*There might be other ways to load images using css if you do not want to use javascript*

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for the detail explanation, but if you could read carefully I don't know the image name while they are loaded as they are fetched from the db?should I then use an ajax request to fetch the images from the db... wouldn't these slow down the page as this is a home page and I don't want users to keep waiting on the home page.

Comment: wouldn't the ajax call help in fetching the name/url of the image?